# how to set a **setting by default in sympy

Tags: python, latex, settings, sympy

I have some equations and I´m using the library sympy to print that equations, more specifically the next line:

```
print(sp.latex(equation))
```

So I want to replace the 'x' in the equation for an "x'_a", to achieve this I made this:

```
print(sp.latex(equation, symbol_names={x:"x'_a"}))
```

My question is: is there a way to set symbol_names={x:"x'_a"} by default, so I won't have to copy that line every time I want to print an equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default settings can be stored in a custom printer created from LatexPrinter. For example:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter
x = sp.symbols('x')
myprinter = LatexPrinter({"symbol_names": {x: "x'_a"}})
```

Now you can do `myprinter.doprint(x**2)` and get `"x'_a^{2}"`... which, incidentally, isn't valid LaTeX so you better use the name `{x: "{x'_a}"}`.

But in practice it's probably easier to define your printing function.

```
def mylatex(expr):
    return sp.latex(expr, symbol_names={x: "{x'_a}"})
```

and then use `mylatex(x**2)`.